# How Can I Create Dynamic Row Inside Grid View On Basis of DatePicker

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I want to add row inside grid view inside grid view on basis of date picker selection.

**Explanation :** I have two Date Picker one represents `From Date` and another represents for `To Date` Suppose User select From Date as `11-NOV` and ToDate as `13-NOV` in that scenario Date Difference will be `TWO` So I want to add `Two` row inside grid view.

**I am trying Like**

1. Calculating No of days from Date selection
2. Using For loop to Create no of Rows

But I don't understand how can i create Multiple New rows inside ASPxGridView?

I dont have such code to show can any one help me on same ?

Comment: is that `gridview` binded to `DataTable`?

Comment: Yes grid already binded with datatable